# What is the MIME type of a .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mime-types

Does anybody know what is the official MIME type of the Apache's directory-associated configuration file format (.htaccess)? The Web is flooded with answers to a keyword-sharing question on adding MIME types with mod_mime/.htaccess, but this is not the case. The only thing I'd like to know is the MIME type of such file.

Comment: A .htaccess file is  not supposed to be shared. Therefore it doesn't need a mime type.

Comment: @bart That's right – these files are not meant for being shared. However, one may sometimes want to share/reference/attach such file for educational or technical reasons. Also, modern file managers have MIME-based file association and there is a trend to classify every piece of data in this convenient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Caja (MATE Desktop's file manager) a .htaccess file's MIME-type is 'application/x-extension-htaccess'.